# Proving that $fg$ are integrable in a bounded set $S$ if $f$,$g$ are integrables in $S$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, riemann-integration

Let $f,g: S \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ Riemannintegrable functions in a bounded set $S \subset { \mathbb{R} }^{ n }$.

Then $fg: S \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ it is also integrable in $S$.

In effect: f,g integrables in $S$ implies by definition that

${ f }_{ S }(x)=\begin{cases} f(x)\quad if\quad x\in S \\ 0\quad else \end{cases}$ $\quad$ and $\quad$
${ g }_{ S }(x)=\begin{cases} g(x)\quad if\quad x\in S \\ 0\quad else \end{cases}$

They are integrable in a rectangle $Q\subset { \mathbb{R} }^{ n }$ such that $S\subset Q$.

By this, the set's ${ D }_{ { f }_{ S } }$ and ${ D }_{ { g }_{ S } }$ of discontinuities of ${ f }_{ S }$ and ${ g }_{ S }$ in $Q$ respectively, have measure zero in ${ \mathbb{R} }^{ n }$.

Now we define ${ f }_{ S }\cdot { g }_{ S }:Q\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ the product function between ${ f }_{ S }$ and ${ g }_{ S }$.

We have ${ f }_{ S }\cdot { g }_{ S }(x)={ f }_{ S }(x)\cdot { g }_{ S }(x)=\begin{cases} f(x)\cdot g(x)\quad if\quad x\in S\quad  \\ 0\quad else \end{cases}:={ (fg) }_{ s }(x)$

and so $dom({ (fg) }_{ s })=dom({ f }_{ S })\cap dom({ g }_{ S })$.

Thus ${ D }_{ { (fg) }_{ s } }={ D }_{ { f }_{ S } }\cap { D }_{ { g }_{ S } }$ where ${ D }_{ { (fg) }_{ s } }$ is the set of discontinuities of ${ (fg) }_{ s }$ in $Q$ and therefore have measure zero in ${ \mathbb{R} }^{ n }$.

Thus ${ (fg) }_{ s }$ is Riemann-integrable in $Q$, 
and this implies by definition that $fg:S\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is Riemann-integrable in $S$ and also:
$\int _{ S }^{  }{ fg } =\int _{ Q }^{  }{ { (fg) }_{ s } } $ $\blacksquare $

(My question is whether this proof is successful)

Comment: Is this correct proof?

Comment: Seems fine, though you need to show or at least explicitly assert that if $fg $ is discontinuous at a point then either $f $ or $g $ must be. A more direct proof would be to note that Riemann integrable functions are bounded and use this to estimate $f (x) g (x) - f (y) g (y) $ (the same way you show that of $x_n \to x $ and $y_n \to y $ then $x_n y_n \to xy $). It is useful to do this proof for later because it turns out this result is very much false in the Lebesgue setting, with the problem arising with unbounded functions.